Are There Any Recomendation of Aircraft Design Books Written By Russian Author?
I've read many aircraft design books, such as the one written by Roskam (Vol 1-8), Raymer, and Torenbeek. I'm curious if there any aircraft design book written by any Russian author, which may they've used a different approach in accomplisihing the aircraft's DRO. If there any book recommendation, just let me know.
I've read many Russian aircraft history book written by Yefim Gordon, but the one I'm interested is in the design process (not the historical story).

This is not an answer, but there's a blog which lists public domain english translations of russian technical books, Mir Books. Their aerodynamics category might be of use to you. During the cold war, most of these titles would be translated by USFG so you can also see them on DTIC, but the blog collects a number of them.

While I can appreciate the reason for the close, it's not clear to me where else on stack exchange one might go to ask for books on Soviet era russian aircraft design.

An old book (1972 or so) is available from discover.dtic.mil Preliminary Design of an Aircraft, the dtic number is AD0741485.
Also, NASA translation AERODYNAMICS AND FLIGHT DYNAMICS OF TURBOJET AIRCRAFT published in 1969 may be of interest. It is on archive.org

